# Is compress available from homebrew?

Tags: compression, homebrew

It is hard to search for "compress". Could anybody let me know where `compress` is availabe on homebrew? Thanks.

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucompres.htm

Comment: There is no need as Apple already supplies `/usr/bin/compress` as part of macOS. AFAIK, most folk prefer `gzip` or `pigz` nowadays.

Comment: OK. But is there an idependent development of `compress`? If that is case, how to use the latest version?